# JAVA BitSet setting

Tags: java, bitset

I'm developing in Java (JDK 1.8) and manipulating BitSets. I came accross
a strange issue.

I'm instantiating a BitSet of size 160 like:

```
BitSet example = new BitSet(160);
```

I want to check the size using the size() method that gives the number of bits in the bitset. In the documentation it is said that the constructor with an int N as parameter is creating a bitset of N bits.

But when I do check the size **right after** with

```
example.size()
```

I obtain the value

```
192
```

I do not understand why, does anyone came across this kind of problem ?
link to documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: From the doc: _Creates a bit set whose initial size is **large enough** to explicitly represent bits with indices in the range 0 through nbits-1._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `BitSet` constructor creates a `BitSet` "whose initial size is large enough to explicitly represent" bits in the range given by the parameter. So the actual `size` will be *at least* the number you give in the parameter, but *not* necessarily equal to that number.

The reason it uses 192 in particular is that 192 is a fairly nice binary number: 64 * 3.

Comment: Ok I see it now, thank you very much! So I guess there is no way to create a bitset that contains exactly the number of bits given in the constructor. I'll use a simple array.

Comment: @thiout_p Why do you need a bitset with *exactly* a certain size? Have you determined that the memory constraints for the program you're building are really that strict?

Comment: @RedRobotHood It is just that I have to implement a model that is a chunk of bits and I wanted to stick to it as much as possible but I'll do otherwise. Thank you for pointing out the important word in the doc!

Comment: @thiout_p The thing is, assuming you really are just dealing with a long string of bits *as* bits, using `BitSet` would be both fast and convenient. The only reason not to use it would be if the extra padding bits really take up too much RAM for your purposes, which I find unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Because the BitSet is actually used long[] to store 0/1 .

```
private void initWords(int nbits) {
    words = new long[wordIndex(nbits-1) + 1];
}
```